# E: Held packages were changed and -y was used without --allow-change-held-packages

Tags: 20.04, php

I got error while trying to install `php 7.4` on Ubuntu 20.04 with the following command

```
add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php && add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/apache2 && apt install -y php7.4 libapache2-mod-php7.4 php7.4-common php7.4-gmp php7.4- curl php7.4-intl php7.4-mbstring php7.4-xmlrpc php7.4-mysql php7.4-bcmath php7.4-gd php7.4-xml php7.4-cli php7.4-fpm php7.4- zip php7.4-imap
```

Comment: Do you have a question?   Your question text should be complete; as some browser/devices don't show the title/heading when the question is viewed; and your question text appears to be paste without formatting or anything else.

Comment: Additionally, your single command line is incorrect. You don't have a `sudo apt update` in there, so you're not getting the `ondrej` PPAs unless they were already working.

Answer (score 0):

> E: Held packages were changed and -y was used without --allow-change-held-packages

The reason why you got the above error message is that you did not run `sudo apt update` to refresh the list of available software after adding ppa:ondrej/php  to your software sources, therefore you can't install any packages from it yet.